# How do I test a paperclip URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, paperclip, testunit

I'm using `Test::Unit`, and I'd like to test a paperclip url.

Right now, I have a test that looks like this:

```
  def test_our_custom_url
    dummy = Dummy.new(:image => File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/test/fixtures/12k.png"))
    dummy.save!
    assert_match "/system/images/1/original/12k.png", dummy.image.url
    dummy.reload
    assert_match "/system/images/1/original/12k.png", dummy.image.url
  end
```

And it fails like this:

```
Expected /\/system\/images\/1\/original\/12k.png/ to match "/system/dummies/images/000/000/001/original/12k.png?1352140343".
```

How can I get the `?1352140343` part added to the test?

I see in paperclips source code that they seem to define it [like this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/url_generator.rb):

```
def timestamp_as_needed(url, options)
  if options[:timestamp] && timestamp_possible?
    delimiter_char = url.match(/\?.+=/) ? '&' : '?'
    "#{url}#{delimiter_char}#{@attachment.updated_at.to_s}"
  else
    url
  end
end
```

but doing `dummy.updated_at.to_s` returns a normal date/timestamp, not `1352140343` (in this case).

I'm using local storage, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not good to compare the `?1352140343` part of the url.

you can compare your `received_url.starts_with?(expected_url)` to check only that part of the strings...